# Doxygen how use git hooks for run doxygen before each push?

Tags: git, doxygen, githooks

I search how generate documentation from doxygen using git hooks.
I have already read git hooks example but i see nothing like i want

root project:
|- documentation/
|- src/
|- .git/

for generate doc from root project i do:
 $ doxygen documentation/doc.doxyfile

thanks for your help

Comment: Are you sure you want large amounts of generated HTML in your repo?

Comment: or do another commit. On your repo you put only your source code? Me i put source and documentation. Just i want a documentation up to date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no pre-push hook.

And even if there were, I highly doubt you'd want to generate *and commit* a huge amount of HTML.

What you may want to do, however, is trigger something from the post-update hook of the repository you've pushed to. It could update a non-bare clone and run doxygen in that, leaving the results somewhere public.

Comment: last thing could be interesting, did you have an example?